# Mechanize , SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python, html

So I am trying to create a python script to automate filling in forms

My script is this :

```
import mechanize
import re

br = mechanize.Browser()

interletter = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp"

br.open(interletter)

for link in br.links():
    targel_url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp"

    if interletter == targel_url:
        print "Form found!"

br.select_form(nr=0)

br.select_form(name="FirstName")= "Josiah"
br.select_form(name="LastName")= "Loh"

result = br.submit()
```

The website which I used to test is this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

May I know why did the error pop up and how can I solve it?

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with `br.select_form(name="FirstName")= "Josiah" `? As the error says, that's a function call, you can't assign to it.

Comment: What was the error that popped up?

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that this bit of code is looking for a particular form:

```
for link in br.links():
    targel_url = "https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp"

    if interletter == targel_url:
        print "Form found!"
```

But all it will do is print "Form found!" 269 times. That is because all your code is doing in the loop is compare the values of `interletter` and `targel_url`, both of which have the same value, so the test always succeeds.

Start by getting this bit of the code to do something useful. It looks as though it is trying to find a particular link. Your program needs to *name* the link it is looking for, and then compare that name with `link.url`. Without knowing the name of the link you are looking for it's hard to help you with the error you are actually reporting.